Flutter: Decryption in Isolate not updating UI with decrypted messages
I'm implementing a chat application in Flutter where messages need to be decrypted using a separate isolate to prevent UI blocking. However, I'm encountering an issue where the decrypted messages are not replacing the placeholder text in the UI.
Here's my current setup:

I initialize a decryption isolate in initState:

void initDecryptionIsolate() async {
  decryptionIsolate = await Isolate.spawn(decryptionIsolateEntryPoint, receivePort.sendPort);
  receivePort.listen(handleIsolateMessage);
}


I send decryption requests to the isolate:

void sendDecryptionRequest(String messageId, String? encryptedText, String auth) {
  if (encryptedText != null && encryptedText.isNotEmpty) {
    decryptionIsolate?.controlPort.send({
      'messageId': messageId,
      'encryptedText': encryptedText,
      'auth': auth,
    });
  }
}


The isolate processes the request and sends back the decrypted message:

static void decryptionIsolateEntryPoint(SendPort sendPort) {
    final ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
    sendPort.send(receivePort.sendPort);
    print('Decryption isolate started');
    receivePort.listen((message) {
      print('Received message in decryption isolate: $message');
      if (message is Map<String, dynamic>) {
        final auth = message['auth'];
        final messageId = message['messageId'];
        final encryptedText = message['encryptedText'];

        if (messageId != null && encryptedText != null && auth != null) {
          try {
            final decryptedText =
                SecureMessageHandler().decryptMessage(encryptedText, auth);
            sendPort.send({
              'messageId': messageId,
              'decryptedText': decryptedText,
            });
          } catch (e) {
            sendPort.send({
              'messageId': messageId,
              'decryptedText': 'Error: Failed to decrypt message',
            });
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }



The main isolate handles the decrypted message:

void handleIsolateMessage(dynamic message) {
    print('Received message in main isolate: $message');
    if (message is Map<String, String>) {
      final messageId = message['messageId'];
      final decryptedText = message['decryptedText'];
      if (messageId != null && decryptedText != null) {
        setState(() {
          decryptedMessageCache[messageId] = decryptedText;
        });
        appState.updateMessage({
          '_id': messageId,
          'plain': decryptedText,
          'chatroomId': appState.chatroom.value,
        });
      }
    }
  }

Despite this setup, the UI is not updating with the decrypted messages. The placeholder text remains visible, and the console only shows:
flutter: Decryption isolate started
flutter: Received message in main isolate: SendPort

What am I missing in this implementation to ensure that the decrypted messages are properly displayed in the UI?
My observation is that the message parameter being sent to the handleIsolateMessage function is of type SendPort and not the expected String Map.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

may i ask why? chat messages are relatively short (up to few hundreds of characters), so why to run a cannon for a small fly? but even you DO need it try IsolateChannel for 2 way isolate communication

I don't know what's wrong with your implementation, but I'd suggest to try compute instead: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html it uses isolates internally but it's simpler to use

@pskink, true, i have an implementation where messages are decrypted and cached so they are not decrypted again, and this is infact a one time thing, however, i am considering a process where a user logs out and logs in, now a conversation that MAY contain thousands of messages will need to be decrypted which can block the UI.

it will not block if you do in your loop (from time to time - like 16ms) a small "nap" bu calling await Future.delayed(napDuration)

also you can play with scheduleTask as it is called "between frames"

Isolate.run() is even more flexible than compute() and should be preferred in modern code.

You shouldn't use the control port to send requests to your isolate.
Use the receiverPort you generated on step 3 :
sendPort.send(receivePort.sendPort);

You are correctly sending it back to the main isolate but you are not catching it on the other side (step 4) :
  SendPort? _workerPort;

  void handleIsolateMessage(dynamic message) {
    print('Received message in main isolate: $message');
    // Add this
    if (message is SendPort) {
      _workerPort = message;
    } 
    else if (message is Map<String, String>) {
      final messageId = message['messageId'];
      final decryptedText = message['decryptedText'];
      if (messageId != null && decryptedText != null) {
        setState(() {
          decryptedMessageCache[messageId] = decryptedText;
        });
        appState.updateMessage({
          '_id': messageId,
          'plain': decryptedText,
          'chatroomId': appState.chatroom.value,
        });
      }
    }
  }

So then in your sendDecryptionRequest you could do so :
void sendDecryptionRequest(String messageId, String? encryptedText, String auth) {
  if (encryptedText != null && encryptedText.isNotEmpty) {
    _workerPort?.send({
      'messageId': messageId,
      'encryptedText': encryptedText,
      'auth': auth,
    });
  }
}

I strongly recommend you to read carefully the great article from Dart site : Isolates which explains it all in detail and provides a full sample of code with error handling and race-conditions management.
Another way to do it would be to use the package WorkerManager which might fit your needs.

Thank you for your recommendation. I would like to mark your answer if you could provide the solution. It may be useful to someone else that comes across the same issue. I will also check out the worker_manager package

from your answer, it seems you're suggesting assigning SendPort to ReceivePort. A value of type 'SendPort' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'ReceivePort'.
